# Change language of captureAudio()

Tags: codenameone

I'm making an app for **French** users and one of its functionnality is capturing audio. To do that, I'm using the method captureAudio(), called when a button is clicked, like so :

```
Capture.captureAudio(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent evt) {
            [...]
        }
});
```

The problem is that it opens a pre-built page in **English** and I want it in **French** but I don't know if I can change it.

Here the screenshot of the page :

[image]

I tried to change the localization with a custom French one without great success.

So if someone know if it's possible and if it's the case, how to do it, it would be nice.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this https://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---localizetranslate-my-application-apply-i18nl10n-internationalizationlocalization-to-my-app.html

You need to install a resource bundle and override the `Cancel`, `Save` keys.

Comment: Thank you Shai, it works ! It's what I did but I was overriding `cancel` and `save` without the caps so nothing changed.